# Why am I seeing "Undefined index: und" when I'm using LANGUAGE_NONE?

Tags: hooks

I've never seen this before, I'm getting an

> Undefined index: und in mymodule_page_alter...

on a line where I'm checking this

```
$node->field_override_ads[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] == 0
```

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps `LANGUAGE_NONE` needs to be inside quotes, `'LANGUAGE_NONE'` ?

Comment: No, it is a constant.

Comment: I think your site is multi-lingual. So, try using global variable language and using that convert your code to like below. Hope this will solve your problem.

global $language;
$node->field_override_ads[$language->language][0]['value'] == 0

Answer (score 0):

```
if(count($node->field_override_ads) && $node->field_override_ads[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] == 0)
```

You need to check if a value even exists before checking the value. And I'd actually write it this way:

```
if(count($node->field_override_ads) && !$node->field_override_ads[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not a bug, it's quite normal for a field to have no value.

You should check using Drupal's API though, it will bypass the issue your code introduces:

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_override_ads');
if (count($items)) {
  $val = $items[0]['value'];
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have checked the API, you're right, I was confused by the undefined 'und' index, which is actually the same as LANGUAGE_NONE.